# GA4 showing far fewer page views (50% or less) than UA

Tags: seo, google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4, page-views

I have configured Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) and GA4 across all of the pages on my website.

I have verified that Google Tag exists on each of the pages using Google Tag Assistant.

If I see a pageview report then I am getting a lot of discrepancies. There are about 50% or less Pageviews in GA4 as compared to UA.

For example,
My website has **/success-stories/** section.

- Time period: 1st June, 2023 to 30th June 2023
- UA shows: 2801 pageviews across 221 pages.
- GA4 shows: 1456 pageview across 11 pages.

Similarly we have a **/glossary/** section

- Time period: 1st June, 2023 to 30th June 2023
- UA shows: 3555 pageviews across 160 pages.
- GA4 shows: 1974 pageview across 20 pages.

Following reports are followed:

- UA: Behavior --> Site Content --> All pages and then apply filter
- GA4: Reports --> Engagement --> Pages and Screens

For each GA4 reports, Thresholding is applied for each reports. Is that the reason why there are less pageviews? I am not trying to see the demographics, so not sure why the threshold is applied.

We aren't able to check individual page's performance.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in this YouTube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5E6hZayk1mQ

I had activated `Settings --> Reporting Identity --> Blended`.

Because of this, I had a threshold applied. When I changed Reporting Identity from `Blended` to `Device-based` then I got a report for all pages.